# Is there a variant of watch that only refreshes upon receiving a signal?

Tags: signals, watch

I have a window that runs a somewhat expensive `watch  git log ...` incantation — expensive enough that it actually looks more like `watch -n30 timeout 10 git log ...` so that it doesn't excessively impair my system.

However, this needn't run every 30 seconds. It only needs to run whenever I run a git command. If `watch` supported it, I could just send a SIGUSR1 signal to `watch` whenever I wanted to update it, and that would save a lot of computational power.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you use `watch` when you don't want it time-based? If you want it signal-based, create a shell function and call it when SIGUSR1 is received.

Comment: If you are going to the bother of issuing a kill command, why not just `alias` the `git` command and use your read line `previous-history` (default key Ctrl-p) to reissue the alias?

Comment: @Marco because the command is only now starting to become enough of a tax on system load to bother. I don't honestly see much of a difference between "run this program when you get a timer interrupt and show the results" and "run this program when you get a signal and show the results". Take Stefan's short program: now I have to put in code to only show the first few lines of the program (how many?), it redraws the pane even if nothing has changed, etc. :)

Comment: @DravSloan I was thinking something like a post-commit hook or similar, actually.

Comment: (Please do not mistake my previous comment as lack of gratitude towards Stefan. It's awesome that he took that much time off his day to write that answer. I'm just explaining why I wanted use watch or, failing that, something very similar.)

Comment: `watch` only triggers by time that's why you can't use `watch` if you want a signal-based trigger. It's as simple as that. So the question becomes “how to run an executable when a certain signal is received?” And you received several answers. But none of them fits your purpose apparently. If a question solves your problem, vote it up and accept it. If it doesn't, leave a comment, why not. I guess you're overcomplicating things here. Or I just don't grasp the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This can be a shell script.
You need it to:

1. do nothing all the time
2. run a hook on a signal

A trap such as `trap 'git log' SIGUSR1` will accomplish `2.`.
`1.` can be approximately emulated with 
`sleep $aLongTime` and perfectly done with:

```
tmp=`mktemp`; echo 'int main(){ pause(); return 0; }' > "$tmp";
gcc -x c "$tmp" -o pause #create a `pause` executable
```

Then your shell script can be:

```
echo $$ #identify self
trap 'git log' SIGUSR1 
while :; do ./pause; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small python 2.6 program for that purpose:

```
import signal,sys,os

cmdString = " ".join(sys.argv[1::]).strip()

def handler(sig,frame):
        if sig == signal.SIGUSR1:
                refresh()
        elif sig == signal.SIGINT:
                print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
                sys.exit(0)

def refresh():
        os.system(cmdString)
        print "\n"
        signal.pause()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
print('Press Ctrl+C to exit')
refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat dirty but it kind of works.

`while :; do watch -n3600 git log ...; sleep 0.5; done`

This relies on the fact that watch quits when receiving USR1. Whenever the signal is required, however, an error message gets written to the terminal. Suppressing it with `2>/dev/null` does not work: it makes `watch` think it's not talking to a terminal and the "User defined signal" message still appears.

The sleep is required in order to let you ctrl-c of the loop somewhat cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell function and call it when a particular (or several)
signals are received. `watch` is the wrong tool for the job. It triggers when
a certain time has passed. You want to trigger not based on time but on
signals.

Here is a simple shell script demonstrating that feature:

```
#!/bin/sh

gitlog() {
  clear
  git log
}

while :; do
  trap gitlog USR1
done

exit 0
```

Test with `kill <PID> -SIGUSR1`. You can still kill that script with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.